# iOS5 app is not listed in Notification Center

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification, nsnotificationcenter

My app uses Local Notifications to communicate with the user.  The legacy code for iOS4 is working well, but in iOS5, notifications are not shown.   After reading on the web, I added the following in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | 
                                                                      UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
                                                                      UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
```

I still do not see the app in the Notification Center.  Is anything more required to make the app being listed in the Notification Center?

Sam.

Comment: Check your Settings.app on the device (you (the user) can control which apps are allowed to appear there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to have a provisioning profile for your app that allows for push notifications. If something goes wrong when registering for push notifications, your app delegate will get notified via [`application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application%3adidFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError%3a). The error object will contain relevant information. Use it to verify that nothing goes wrong.

Comment: Long and complicated process - but it did work.  The app is now listed in the Notification Center.    T H A N K S!!

Comment: My application registered for remote notification successfully but not in Notification Center. Why?